# My simple app has stopped and issue with incrementation in sharedPreferences

Tags: android

I'm creating my first app and I dont know why, when I click on "New Game" I get notification "appka has stopped". Also I have question is my incrementation of sharedPreferences correct?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView, textView2, solution;
int MyNumber, userNumber, guessCont;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        solution = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.lewan.appka", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
        }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

public void NewGame(View view){

    Random rand = new Random();
    MyNumber = rand.nextInt((5-0)+1)+0;
    guessCont =0;
    textView.setText("Time guessed: " + guessCont);
    solution.setText(MyNumber);
    }

public void guess(View view) {

    guessCont++;
    EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    userNumber = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    String message = "";
    if(userNumber!=MyNumber){
    message = "wrong number";
    }
    else if(userNumber==MyNumber){
    message = "correct number";
    int i=0;
    editor.putInt("Amount of games",i++);
    editor.commit();
    textView2.setText("Amount of games: " + sharedPreferences);
    }
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
    toast.show();
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    textView.setText("Time guessed: " + guessCont);

    }
    }
```

and .xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guess!"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
    android:onClick="guess"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Game"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="NewGame"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time Guess"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Amount of games"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Solution (for testing)"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

bla bla bla, my post is mostly code i need some more bla bla

EDIT: errors from Log

```
08-05 10:44:03.538  29161-29161/com.example.lewan.appka E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3606)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17367)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17367)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
            at com.example.lewan.appka.MainActivity.NewGame(MainActivity.java:65)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17367)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I believe you are getting junk values in `textView2` edit text

Comment: @HelicoP where do you call NewGame and Guess() functions ??

Comment: I dont know exatly what do you mean  - I just add "onclick" in buttons and then create methods for this. I still have something to add?

Answer (score 1):

I think change the code

```
textView2.setText("Amount of games: " + sharedPreferences);
```

in to

```
textView2.setText("Amount of games: " + sharedPreferences.getString("Amount of games","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change ?

Basically you have used **Integer** value for text set on Textview, so you have to do typecast with **String**.

```
solution.setText(MyNumber);
```

to

```
solution.setText(""+MyNumber);
```

Hope this will help you.